# Let $f: \Bbb S^2 \rightarrow \Bbb RP^2$ and $g: \Bbb RP^2 \rightarrow \Bbb S^2$ be continuous maps between sphere and projective plane.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $f : \Bbb S^2 \rightarrow \Bbb RP^2$ and $g : \Bbb RP^2 \rightarrow \Bbb S^2$ be continuous maps between sphere and projective plane.

Show that $g  \circ f :\Bbb S^2 \rightarrow \Bbb S^2$ is not homotopic to the identity map.

Should I start with the fundamental group of $\Bbb RP^2$ isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_2$?

Comment: Yes — great place to start!.

Comment: @TedShifrin so f sends a pair of antipodal points on the sphere to their equivalence class in RP2. this implies for x∈RP2 there is a set bijection π1(RP2)--->f^-1(x). so it must be Z2. How to deal with g?

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm curious to know the argument you had in mind. I thought maybe some lifting argument would work, but I couldn't finagle the details correctly without passing to degrees of maps or something like that

Comment: @AndresMejia: I had in mind the homology argument, as well. I said "to start." :) I think a mod-2 degree argument works fine: Since $f$ has to lift to a map $\tilde f\colon S^2\to S^2$, the mod-2 degree of $g\circ f$ has to be $0$. Oops.

Comment: @TedShifrin yes, that is the basic idea  :) Okay good to know, I was curious if there was something clever with $\pi_1$ I was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use integral $H_2$ instead.

Note that $H_2(S^2)=\mathbb Z$ while $H_2(\mathbb RP^2)=0$.

Then $f_*:H_2(S^2) \to H_2(\mathbb RP^2)$ is the zero map, and $g_*$ is also the zero map.

It follows that $g_*f_*=0$ while $id_*=1$ by functoriality.

Answer (score 0):

Using algebraic invariants is definitely the way to go about this. However, in this particular case, the fundamental group may not be the right algebraic invariant.

Let me first illustrate the kind of argument you can give, by using the fundamental group to show that $fg: \mathbb{R}P^2 \to \mathbb{R}P^2$ cannot be homotopic to the identity map. This is of course not the function composition you asked about, but the argument for $fg$ is similar (I'll come back to that in a bit).

Let us collect a few necessary facts: $\pi_1(\mathbb{S}^2) = 0$ and $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}P^2) = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Any continuous map $h: X \to Y$ induces a homomorphism $h_*: \pi_1(X) \to \pi_1(Y)$ of fundamental groups, homotopic maps induce the same homomorphism and this is functorial: it respects function composition (so $(h h')_* = h_* h'_*$) and sends the identity to the identity.

Suppose that $fg$ is homotopic to the identity, and aim for a contradiction. We must have that $(fg)_* = f_* g_*$ is the identity, but then the identity on $\mathbb{Z} / 2\mathbb{Z}$ factors through the trivial group 0, which is impossible. More precisely: $f_* g_* = Id$ means that $g_*$ is injective, but $g_*$ is a map from $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ to $0$. So $g_*$ cannot be injective, which gives us our contradiction.

This argument does not work for the composition $gf$, because $g_* f_*$ is a map from the trivial group $0$ to itself, and there is no problem with this factoring through any other group. However, there are other algebraic invariants. The first that pops into the mind is singular homology, so you may want to try that (and yes, this will work). I will leave it to you to adjust the argument to use singular homology.

Comment: You can contract any loop on the sphere, therefore $\pi_1(\mathbb{S}^2)=0\neq\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @logarithm I am an idiot, and I was thinking about $\mathbb S^1$ all the time. Thank you for pointing that out, I will edit and correct my answer right away.

Comment: @Andres the composition $fg$ is a map $\mathbb R P^2 \to \mathbb R P^2$. Now, as I said, this is not the composition in the question, but it's meant to serve as an example (where one can actually use the fundamental group). That way Darren can still try to replicate the argument himself for the actual question.

Comment: @MarkKamsma got it.